# Tensorflow/Keras multi-label classifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have just started developing some simple classifier in Tenosrflow and I've started using this example on Tensorflow site: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification

Now I want my model to get images like this as features:

[image: Corresponding label: [1, 0]]

[image: Corresponding label: [3, 0]]

[image: Corresponding label: [1, 3]]

These images should have, as corresponding labels, three arrays: [1,0], [3,0] and [1,3].
My problem is: how can I load into the model these kind of labels (i.e. labels that are arrays and not a single scalar)?
When I try as in the example down here, the only thing I got is an error message that I won't report here because they are generated from my lack of knowledge on the thing that I'm trying to do.

Additional question: how should the last neural layer be? How many neurons should it have?

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import skimage
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
import csv
import numpy as np

names = ['Cerchio', 'Quadrato', 'Stella']

images = []
labels = [[]]

test_images = []
test_labels = [[]]
final_images = []

for i in range(1, 501):
    images.append(skimage.data.imread("{0}.bmp".format(i)))
for i in range(501, 601):
    test_images.append(skimage.data.imread("{0}.bmp".format(i)))

for i in range(601, 701):
    final_images.append(skimage.data.imread("{0}.bmp".format(i)))

file = open("labels.csv", "rU")

reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")


for row in reader:
    for i in range(0, 499):
        if int(row[i]) < 10:
            labels.append([int(int(row[i])/10), 0])
        else:
            labels.append([int(int(row[i])/10), int(row[i])%10])
    for i in range(500, 600):
        if int(row[i]) < 10:
            test_labels.append([int(int(row[i])/10), 0])
        else:
            test_labels.append([int(int(row[i])/10), int(row[i])%10])


file.close()

images28 = np.array(images)
images28 = rgb2gray(images28)
test_images28 = np.array(test_images)
test_images28 = rgb2gray(test_images28)
final_images28 = np.array(final_images)
final_images28 = rgb2gray(final_images28)

labels = np.array(labels)
test_labels = np.array(test_labels)
print(labels)

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 56)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(), 
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(images28, labels, epochs=5)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images28, test_labels)

print('Test accuracy:', test_acc)
a = input()
img = final_images28[int(a)]

print(img.shape)

img = (np.expand_dims(img, 0))
print(img.shape)

predictions_single = model.predict(img)
print(predictions_single)
print(names[np.argmax(predictions_single)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Googling around and toying with my program, I found the solution: a multi-hot encoded array.
In this array, if I have a position for a circle, a square, a star and the blank space (hence a 4 position array), I can feed to my model labels that have a '1' in each corresponding space.
E.g. (referring to the example above):

- [1, 0, 1, 0]
- [1, 0, 0, 1]
- [0, 0, 1, 1]

This did work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

One way is just map the array labels into an index, like [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]->0, [[1,0],[0,0],[0,0]]->1,... etc. You'll have 3^6=729 possible labels. If these forms on the images are standard you probably can use just simplest classificator with no hidden layers so it's gonna be dim1xdim2x729 trainable weights. If they are not standard you will be better off using convolutional layers.

You can probably also use fully convolutional model for this problem that is returning 3 dimensional tensor as an output. In this case you can use multidimensional labels. But then you'll have to write custom loss function for it.

Comment: If I hadn’t been clear, the images are given one at time and just one bidimensional label as output at time. So I’ll have just 2^4 different outputs that, according to your suggestion, I’ll map. Though I wanted an array as output because I do not want to remap everything if I increase the numbers of different images that I feed to it (and then combine toghether).